# ESLint: 8.0.0 Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint'

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Could you help me, I've got this error when I try building a project?

> Oops! Something went wrong! :(

> ESLint: 8.0.0

> TypeError: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'src.eslintrc': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
> Referenced from: src.eslintrc

package.json

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
        "browserslist": "^4.17.3",
        "eslint": "^8.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
        "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    }
```

.eslintrc

```
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
```

Comment: hey Alexei, did you run ``npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`` when adding your esLint?

Comment: hi, I've just updated eslint to version 8.0.0 today and some libs include         `"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",`

Comment: Have you made sure that you do not have any trailing comma's? I see in your example that ``"prettier": "^2.3.2"`` has a comma at the end but shouldn't because it's not valid JSON.

Comment: yep, I cut out extra dependencies.
Also I created clean project with only "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0", "eslint": "^8.0.0" and it doesn't work too

Comment: strange that you're having compatibility issues. I followed : https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/HEAD/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md and have ``^8.0.0"`` for eslint in my ``package.json`` and it works fine. Did downgrading your version help you?

Comment: yes, it helped me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I saw this error trying to use version 4.x.x of the @typescript-eslint packages:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.1",
    ...
}
```

Fix was to update these to the version `"^5.3.1"`

Answer (score 32):

I did this and it work just fine for me

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
"eslint": "^8.1.0",
```

Update those three packages

Then run in the root of your project this command to update the packages

```
npm i
```

And it will work fine

Comment: https://github.com/JanDez/next-prisma-railway

Check the log from Actions and how I fixed

Answer (score 20):

There is probably an ESM compatibility problem with one of the packages, so either you must make sure **all your deps** are ESM compatible or lock eslint to 7.32.0 & upgrade the plugins as (I'd also recommend to add typescript to your dev deps):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
```

To achieve this you can run:

```
npm i --save-dev typescript @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.6.0 @typescript-eslint/parser@5.6.0 eslint@7.32.0
```

The `--save-dev` part is to install them as dev deps as they are not required aside from build && dev

Answer (score 7):

This issue was quite persistent for me.  The simple solution that worked was to `reload VS Code`.

[image]

Comment: For me, this worked, but also found that running `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server` also worked

Answer (score 1):

for me upgrading my node version from 12.12.0 to 16.0.0 resolved the issue. Looks like a problem with old node version.

Answer (score 1):

i upgraded node.js version to 16 and now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3982

It seems to be a compatibility problem

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  You have to downgrade to version 7.32.0 for it to work properly with VS Code. - J

Comment: @Jonathanprobably because this is better suited to be written as a comment only and not as an answer (following https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358727/are-there-any-guidelines-to-handle-one-line-correct-code-only-answers-in-vario), does not gives a direct answer, doesn't solve the problem (here in this answer) and is more like a hint than an answer (to an external url which can break and the answer therefore would contain zero useful info), so it would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when my node version wasn't compatible with the react version I was using. Check the logs and update to a compatible version of nodejs