# Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs' : Unexpected token '.'

Tags: webstorm, typescript-eslint

I’m working on a React project with TypeScript and ESLint. I have the following versions of `eslint` and `typescript-eslint` in my package.json file

```json
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.3.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
"eslint": "^8.45.0",
```

I also have the following `.eslintrc.cjs` file:

```js
/* eslint-env node */

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: true,
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],
  },
}
```

For every file in WebStrom I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs': Unexpected token '.'

I have tried to update my Node version to 20.5.1, reinstall all the dependencies, and validate my `.eslintrc.cjs` file, but nothing seems to work. My colleagues who are using the same files don’t have any problems.

I also tried all the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513869/eslint-8-0-0-failed-to-load-plugin-typescript-eslint).

Does anyone know what could be causing this error and how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Finally found the solution, It's the the IDE causing problems

#### step 1

Find the node version used for project

```
node --version
```

#### Step 2

Use the same node version for the IDE interpreter

File -> settings -> Languages & framework -> Node.js

[image]

#### Step 3

If the problem still persists, you can install plugin from Webstorm and from action bar restart the eslint service

[Plugin link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14119-eslint-restart-service-action)

Comment: Step 2) - Node Configuration in IDE fixed it for me - thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try the same with node 18.17.0?

I had a similar problem when i was using node 14.

Comment: I have tried node version 18.17.0 , thinking LTS version of the node could solve the problem but finally the solution was  proper node configuration in IDE